# .htaccess generating a 500 error status

Tags: .htaccess, browser-cache

I'm trying to generate redirecting and caching with the .htaccess file.
Here's my Code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault A86400

<FilesMatch "\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg\png|flv|pdf|swf|mov|mp3|wmv|ppt)$">
  ExpiresDefault A1814400
  Header append Cache-Control "public"
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(xml|txt|html)$">
 ExpiresDefault A259200
 Header append Cache-Control "proxy-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(js|css)$>
 ExpiresDefault A10800
 Header append Cache-Control "proxy-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(php|cgi|pl)$">
 ExpiresDefault A0
 Header set Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must revalidate, max-age=0"
 Header set Pragma "no-cache"
</FilesMatch>
</ifModule>

<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|html|htm|php|xml)$">
 SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)(\.gz)?$">
Header unset ETag
FileETag None
</FilesMatch>
```

If I remove all the caching, and leave only the first three lines, it works fine but without caching:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Take a look into your http servers error log file. That is where errors at runtime are written to. No sense in trying to _guess_ what the error _might_ be, if you can simply read it.

Comment: There is no error regarding that issue in the error log

Comment: An http status 500 certainly will create an entry in the error log file. Maybe you are looking at  the wrong file? Keep in mind that there are different types of log files and also that there might be multiple error log files, for example for separate hosts inside your http server.

Comment: I'm looking at the "error_log" in the root directory. Should I look somewhere else?

Comment: I cannot say. I do not know your setup and configuration. But "root directory" looks pretty strange to me. Check your http servers host configuration. That is where the log file locations are defined.

Comment: OK, found the error log you're talking about - it says "Regex could not be compiled"

Comment: Aha! See? Now we know exactly what the issue is. An invalid regex. Next time you will be much faster to look into the error log. And you will be faster to find out exactly what is wrong. Way better than guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Regex could not be compiled"

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg\png|flv|pdf|swf|mov|mp3|wmv|ppt)$">
```

You have a `\p` token (used to match Unicode code points and would seem to not be supported in Apache config?) - looks like a typo - it should be `|p` (pipe-p).

I did just try this on my own server (Apache 2.4) and got the same error.